# Export q from angular?

Tags: angularjs, debugging, q

For debug purposes I need to export a `$q` service out of `angular` object from global js scope or console. Is there any way to do that ?

Pseudo code:
`var q = voodoo(angular);` or 
`var q = angular.DO().$something`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var $injector = angular.injector(['ng']);
var $q = $injector.get('$q');
var deferred = $q.defer();
... etc
```